# Byte-size enum in Java

Tags: java, android, memory

I have a class of which there may be many instances (on a mobile device), so I'm trying to minimize the size. One of my fields is a "DrawTarget" that indicates whether drawing operations are being ignored, queued to a path or drawn to the display. I would like it to take a single byte or less since there are only 3 possible values, but I would also like it to be friendly code so I don't have hard-coded numbers all over. One thought is to use an enum like:

```
public enum DrawTarget {
    Invisible,
    Path,
    Canvas
}
```

But from what I read, a Java enum doesn't allow you to specify the memory layout -- I can't request that the enum values represent a byte-size value -- and I guess enum values end up being integer-sized values in Java.

So I thought about maybe making an implicit conversion operator in the enum... is this possible in Java? Or is my best option to implement something like this within the enum:

```
public static DrawTarget fromValue(byte value) {
    switch (value) {
    case 0:
        return Invisible;
    case 1:
        return Path;
    default:
        return Canvas;
    }
}
```

and then call DrawTarget.fromValue wherever I want to access the value?

Or should I just create a single-byte class since apparently (from what I read in my research on this) enums are basically just special classes in Java anyway?

```
public class DrawTarget {
    public static final byte Invisible = 0;
    public static final byte Path = 1;
    public static final byte Canvas = 2;
}
```

But how to I represent the value of an enum instance if I use that last solution? I still need a way to allow the "=" operator to accept one of the static fields of the class... like a conversion constructor or an assignment operator overload.

I suspect, however, that any class object, being a reference type, will take more than a byte for each instance. Is that true?

Comment: Unless you are going to have more than a million instances, is there really any point in saving 24 bits per instance? And even at 1 mil instances, you still 'only' save 3MB of memory.

Comment: Mobile devices can impose draconian limits on memory usage. And I'm writing a class that may get incorporated into higher level objects in ways I can't predict. So I can't really optimize for a specific target and want to do some level of generic optimization if it's practical. I'm new to Android development, but I'm thinking my View-derived class might be used to represent a tile an a tile grid of many tiles. It's also recursive and can have instances nested within other instances.

Comment: `DrawTarget.values()[value]` will give you the enum faster than the switch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java enum is a class that has as many instances, as there are values. The instances are produced at class (enum) loading time. Each place where you use an enum variable or an enum attribute, you actually use an ordinary reference to one of the existing enum objects (instances of enums are never created after enum is initialized).

This means that an enum reference costs as much as any other object reference, usually four bytes. Which is really, really, really little.

1. You don't know how much memory does a byte take (really! remember that low level memory management includes plenty of padding!), so any "optimization" based on this will fail. On a given architecture a byte field might take as much memory as an integer field (because it might be faster that way).
2. If you want to write good Java, use enum. Really. The only good reason **not** to use enums, would be if you had a whole array of values, like: `drawTargets[] = new DrawTarget[100000];`
3. If you insist on microoptimizing, just use plain bytes and forget enums; `public static final byte SOMETHING = 1;` is fine for making comparisons (and sucks for debugging).

I have written Android programs for a long time and have never seen such microoptimization pay off. Your case might be the one in a million, but I don't think it is.

Also, to make life simpler for all of us, please consider using Java conventions in Java code: enum instances and public final static fields should be names `LIKE_THIS`, attributes `likeThis` (not `LikeThis`!).

Comment: Can you clarify what you are referring to with the term "attributes" (attributes `likeThis`)?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: I meant class attributes other than public static final ones, like "private int likeThis = 4;". I hope my request doesn't seem too offensive, I really believe that your code it is none of my business and you are certainly free to use any convention you wish. It's just that many people with different backgrounds started writing Android apps, and now most of sources I have seen are a mess: some conventions from C#, some from PHP, some from C, some from C++... it would be nice if we could agree on using on set of rules, and since it's Java, it could as well be Java's :-)

Comment: Not offensive at all. I am relatively new to Java and very interested in writing clean code (it's open source - http://sourceforge.net/projects/picturecode/). I am in the process of re-factoring (renaming) all my enum values/fields/attributes - whatever you want to call them :). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> and I guess enum values end up being integer-sized values in Java.

No, enums are always *classes* in Java. So if you have a field of type `DrawTarget`, that will be a reference - either to `null` or to one of the three instances of `DrawTarget`. (There won't be any more instances than that; it's not like a new instance of `DrawTarget` is created every time you use it.)

I would go with the enum and then measure the memory usage - an enum is *logically* what you want, so take the normal approach of writing the simplest code that works and then *testing* the performance - rather than guessing at where bottlenecks might be.

You *may* want to represent the value as a single byte when serializing, and then convert it back to the enum when deserializing, but other than that I'd stick with the enum type throughout your code if possible.

Comment: And a class reference is an integer-sized value, is it not?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: on Android, I would think so. On 64-bit machines, a reference, AFAIK, is 64-bits long, whereas integers are always 32-bits long.

Comment: Also, I have found, in practice, that it is much more likely that the suggested form of late optimization will never happen than it is that easily-applied optimizations that I can think of as I write turn out to be problematic (at least when there's no trade-off involved as there may be here). So in cases where my code *can* be more optimized without giving up any clarity, I like to optimize to the extent I can as I write.

Comment: @JB Nizet In my world (coming from C++) integers are the OS native sized word, which is 64-bits on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: In what way would using a `byte` not involve a trade-off? With enums you get *far* more expressivity, type safety etc. Obviously I can't force you to avoid premature optimization, but I really, really would urge you to. It's up to you to have the discipline to perform appropriate perf testing.

Comment: The way using a byte would not involve a trade off is if there were a form of enum like C# has where you can inherit from a value type like `enum Status : byte { good, bad, ok }`. So I asked the question to see if something similar existed in Java. But since it doesn't I will just use a simple enum and accept the result that is less optimized than C# would be for now.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: Right. Although in C# you wouldn't get the advantage of polymorphism, the ability for enums to have state, behaviour etc. (You may not need it in this case, but generally Java enums are nicer than C# ones. It's virtually the only aspect of Java which I prefer over C#.)

Comment: Agreed. I already appreciate the unique ability to add other sorts of members to Java enums, and am taking advantage of it, but it's a trade-off. C# is better in one area and Java in another for now. As for discipline to performance test, that can require an awful lot of discipline in some cases with large systems, which many organizations/people don't have. In some cases performance testing to a specific target is not possible or practical because the target  is unknown or variable. But I agree that optimizations with trade-offs should not be made before or without performance testing.

Answer (score 3):

Unless android has some special way of treating enum references, each reference to a DropTarget will indeed take more than one byte in memory. Enums are classes, and enum instances are objects. So a reference to an enum instance takes the same amout of memory as any other object reference.

I wouldn't care much about it unless you have measured that this caused memory problems, though, and that reducing the size would have a significant impact.

What you get from enums, mainly, is type safety. If a method takes a `DropTarget` as argument, you (or coworkers) won't be able to pass anything other than one of the three instances of `DropTarget` (or null). If you use a byte instead, the code is less clear, and anyone could pass any byte value instead of the three authorized byte values.

So, decide which is the most important for you, and choose the solution you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes will only contain a reference to the enum. Only one instance of each enum will be created.

Aside from that, consider using polymorphism to implement the drawing behavior.

If the value of the enum is fixed, instantiate a different subclass for each object depending on its desired drawing behavior.

If the value changes often, you could keep a reference to the desired drawing strategy in the object. Refer to an object with an empty draw() method for objects that should not be drawn. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

enum is special data type, not a class.check oracle documentations for further details.
An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined for it.